# Does native speaker wrongly use the grammar in this particular situation?

Tags: conditional-constructions

See this [video](https://youtu.be/3bubpUzc19c?list=PLhjZRiifarZjbp4hItwNKgGW5IFCXBf4A) at **1:34**, the girl said "**if he weren't in the movie, the Nazis would have still found the ark**".

I think it is the conditional sentence type 3, and we should use past perfect in the "If clause". SO, I think she should say "**if he hadn't been in the movie, the Nazis would have still found the ark**"
Does native speaker wrongly use the grammar  in this particular situation?

Comment: She is using the subjunctive and so "weren't" is correct.

Answer (score 3):

No, it's not incorrect. Native speakers combine tenses in conditional clauses in many more ways than those artificial Conditional 0, 1, 2, and 3 things that are taught in EFL classes and texts. Those things just present example patterns; they don't cover all possible grammatical combinations.